# Django REST - hide deserialized data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to store some data in one of my database field. The data is added to that field while deserialization with POST method. Later when I want to show data with GET method I don't want that one field to be presented.

When I do POST I deserialize that string:

```
{
    "car_id": 3,
    "rating": 3
}
```

Later in `views.py` I do the deserialization while POST:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def car_rate(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        rate_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        rate_serializer = CarRateSerializer(data=rate_data)

        if rate_serializer.is_valid():
            try:
                car_obj = Car.objects.get(pk=rate_data['car_id'])
            except Car.DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'The car with given ID does not exist!'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
            # check if rate is from 1 to 5
            r = rate_serializer.validated_data['rating']
            if int(r) >= 1 and int(r) <= 5:
                rate_serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse({'message':'The rate is in the scope!'})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'message':'The rate is NOT in the scope!'})
        
        return JsonResponse(rate_serializer.errors)
```

And there is my `models.py`:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    avg_rating = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):      # print it when Car instance is needed
        return self.make


class CarRate(models.Model):
    car_id = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='rates',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            default=0)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

The code does works (somehow). For now there can be added rates for one car (multiple rates) with POST moethods. I store the rates in CarRate class and later it will be used to calculate the average rate for a car. I just simply don't want to print it out with GET.

This is my output right now:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "make": "Volkswagen",
    "model": "Golf",
    "rates": [
        4,
        4,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "avg_rating": 0.0
},
```

I simply want the `rates` field to be invisible while printing.

I read about `defer()` method and tried it out, but nothing happened. Any help?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad since you are writing in third person. May you be more specific which field and where? Nevertheless, if I am not wrong have a look at `to_representation()` method.

Comment: Well' you're right, my bad. I edited post and added my actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely don't want that field to be in your database ever, then you can simply remove that field from the Serializer field option (You named that CarRateSerializer)
But if you want that to be in your database but you don't want that to show as output, you can use **extra_kwargs** with **'write_only': True** in your serializer class. I'm giving you an example I used for one of my projects

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Topic
    fields = ['id','title', 'totalMarks', 'status', 'categoryID']
    extra_kwargs = {'categoryID': {'write_only': True}}
```

for your code, you can add this line of code below **fields** in that **class Meta** of your CarRateSerializer

```
extra_kwargs = {'rating': {'write_only': True}}
```

I hope this should solve your issue

Comment: Hell yeah! `write_only` does exactly what I want, except I didn't want to hide `rating` but `rates`.  The thing with `extra_kwargs` didn't work in CarSerializer, but I think because of `read_only` set to True in rates variable. I changed that to `write_only` and it does the same what you wrote. Lesson learned, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `rating` field from, `CarRateSerializer` **OR** you can create a new Serializer for CarRate.